# Creating a query with comits in it

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

So I'm currently trying to build search queries that would find repositories that were committed after 2020-01-01. I grabbed the commit syntax and just basically slammed it onto the query that I already have but it doesn't work. It looks something like this: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:2020-01-01&committer-date:2020-01-01. What am I doing wrong and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me come up with a correct syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Everything runs smoothly when I open the provided url in Chrome. Could you show us the output for when you open it?

Comment: Right, it runs smoothly but I don't think the syntax works. I am trying to find repos that are committed specifically on that data. However, if you remove "&comitter-data:2020-01-01", the results number wouldn't change at all. I have been reading up on search qualifiers and all that on github but can't seem to find the right syntax for commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can used the `pushed` parameter along with the `search` method in the GitHub API.
For example your query could look like:

`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=pushed:>2020-12-01`

NOTE: The `>` in the query means after the given date.

Read more [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-by-when-a-repository-was-created-or-last-updated).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is pushed the same as commit, I am pretty confused with this.

Comment: When you push to a repository, you are making a commit in it. So yes, they are pretty much the same.